# chown: cannot access '/var/lib/odoo': No such file or directory

Tags: python, ubuntu, odoo

I want to install odoo 14 on ubuntu 20.04.2, everytime I want to install odoo's dependencies this error comes up: 
chown: cannot access '/var/lib/odoo': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package odoo (--configure):
installed odoo package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
odoo
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I was following the installation instruction on https://www.candidroot.com/blog/our-candidroot-blog-1/post/how-to-install-odoo-14-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-67 and the error comes up when I run step5.

I tried other solutions but the error is still there.

Answer (score 3):

Just create the folder `/var/lib/odoo` and your problem should be solved.

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/odoo
```

Comment: Is this a bug in the installation script? I though this folder should be created automatically by the installer